# Drop a DataFrame's Column in SparkR

Tags: r, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

I'm wondering if there is a concise method for dropping a DataFrame's column in *SparkR*, such as `df.drop("column_name")` in *pyspark*.

This is the closest I can get:

```
df <- new("DataFrame",
          sdf=SparkR:::callJMethod(df@sdf, "drop", "column_name"),
          isCached=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be achieved by assigning NULL to the Spark dataframe column:

```
df$column_name <- NULL
```

See the original discussion at the related [Spark JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-7280?focusedCommentId=14536866&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-14536866).

Answer (score 3):

**Spark >= 2.0.0**

You can use [`drop`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/reference/drop.html) function:

```
drop(df, "column_name")
```

**Spark < 2.0.0**

You can use the `select` function to select what you need to keep giving it a set of columns with names or Column expressions.

**Usage :**

```
## S4 method for signature 'DataFrame'
x$name
## S4 replacement method for signature 'DataFrame'
x$name <- value
## S4 method for signature 'DataFrame,character'
select(x, col, ...)
## S4 method for signature 'DataFrame,Column'
select(x, col, ...)
## S4 method for signature 'DataFrame,list'
select(x, col)
select(x, col, ...)
selectExpr(x, expr, ...)
```

**Examples :**

```
select(df, "*")
select(df, "col1", "col2")
select(df, df$name, df$age + 1)
select(df, c("col1", "col2"))
select(df, list(df$name, df$age + 1))

# Similar to R data frames columns can also be selected using `$`
df$age
```

You may also be interested in the `subset` function that returns subsets of DataFrame according to given conditions.

I invited you to read the official documentation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/) for more information and examples.

Comment: Thanks Eliasah! I'm familiar with select, I am looking for a method to drop.

Comment: I'm sorry. This is what's available now. We both know that sparkR is still a "new" project.

Comment: I've found in JIRA that drop is implemented in an R style manner, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Leveraging select:

```
drop_columns = function(df, cols) {
                    # Names of columns
                    col_names = df %>% colnames
                    # Filter out column names passed in
                    col_names = col_names[!(col_names %in% cols)]
                    # Select remaining columns
                    df %>% select(col_names)}

df %>% drop_columns(c('column1', 'column2'))
```